# What is the reasonable upper limit of vis extraction for an established magus?

Tags: ars-magica-5

Using the core rule book, Covenants, and The Mysteries as sources, what is the reasonable upper limit of seasonal vim vis extraction of a hermetic alchemist that's 75 years post gauntlet?

Considerations that appear to be synergistic are:

- Lab specialization: vis extraction
- Hermetic alchemy major virtue
- House Verditus bonus to alchemy lab total

Answer (score 1):

*Sub Rosa* #11 (Oct 2012) is your friend. The following numbers are mostly from the article *The Vitruvian Magus*[1] by Mark Lawford[2], p32.

The article is about how do you build a character to use the Hermetic Architecture virtue efficiently, which is a slightly different question to yours.

But towards your question:

**Vis Extraction Laboratory Total (Creo Vis)**

|  | Starting | +10 Years | +20 years | +30 years |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Intelligence | +3 | +3 | +3 | +3 |
| Magic Theory (vis) | 6 | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| Creo | 11 | 13 | 15 | 17 |
| Vim | 10 | 12 | 14 | 14 |
| Bonus from Magical Focus | 10 | 12 | 14 | 14 |
| Lab Bonus | N/A | N/A | 8 | 8 |
| Aura | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| **Total** | 43 | 50 | 64 | 66 |
| **Pawns per Season** | **5** | **5** | **7** | **7** |

Probably not the maximum value, but we can maybe see the direction to the maximum !!?

The most relevant virtues involved:

- Verditius Magic  ArM5 p93 - the number of pawns needed to open a device is reduced by your Craft score. (Thus any Craft bonus virtues e.g. Dwarf Blood are useful)
- Major Magical Focus (Vim) - increase your Lab Total (invest larger devices) by adding the smaller Art twice.
- Verditius Elder Runes - HoH:MC p127 doubles the relevant Arts for your Lab Total. MMF continues to add the original value of the smallest Art.
- Affinity with Magic Theory - improve your max pawns investment: 2*MT pawns in any one season.
- Planetary Magic (prereq for Celestial Magic)
- Celestial Magic - TMRE p48 - reduces the number of pawns needed to open a device for enchantment. Seems to stack with Verditius Magic.
- Major Philosophical Alchemy - TMRE p40 - run vis extraction as a background activity, and in addition save a season's work by opening a device with the produced vis.

[1] Relating to, or being in the architectural style of Marcus Vitruvius Pollio, the author of "De architectura", probably the most widely referenced Roman work on architecture.

[2] An editor of *Sub Rosa*, and author or lead author of at least 7 ArM5 books. See https://www.redcap.org/page/Mark_Lawford for details.